# My computers startup got slow after changing the PCIe which my graphic card was installed

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, pci-express

I recently found that that i had my graphic card installed on the wrong PCIe. Instead of using the 16x one (for Express 3.0) i was using the 8x one. So i just unplugged my graphic card from the 8x and installed it at 16x, my computer powered on, got into windows, it asked to install again the drivers of the graphic card and after all has been done, doing a restart i noticed that at startup it takes much more time than usual.

I unistalled the drivers of the GPU, reboot, installed them again, reboot and still startup is slower than it was.

Am i missing something? Did the change made some damage to the windows?

I am using Windows 7 64bit, Gigabyte Z77m-D3H and Nvidia GTX 660.

Comment: Did you check the Event Viewer?

Comment: Yes, it has errors on boot time. 100, 101 and 103. Checked them online, but couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: use xbootmgr to capture a boottrace: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=140247. If you're unsure how to read it, zip and upload it (skydrive, dropbox, google drive) and insert a link here.

Comment: Interesting topic, i didn't know about it. I'll give it a shot as soon as i get home and ether check the bootimes of each stuff alone or post it here if i can't understand whats wrong. Thanks

Comment: ok. Have you finished a trace?

Comment: Yes, checked the link, did the trace and then followed the instructions on how to make booting faster. And now everything is working good again. If u want post it as an answer, not comment, so i can choose your answer as best.

Comment: @Nick What did you change that made the boot faster?

Comment: I followed the guide from the above link.  You can find it here http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/140262-how-to-speed-up-boot-process-under-windows-vista-or-windows-7/